# AJAX Request to sharepoint REST API But receiving CORS error

Tags: rest, ajax, api, cors

I want to request a sharepoint server with ajax but I get an CORS error :
[image]

How can I solve this issue please

```
  $.ajax({
url: "http://myserver.com" + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef",
async: false,
crossDomain: true,
headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
},
complete: function(request) {
    console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
}, 
error: function(request) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing the request from?

Comment: I’m doing the request from a computer in the same network and the same domain in the DNS

Comment: @rezouanemarimouttou : set the *crossDomain* parameter to false.

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz it's not working I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/fixing-issue-in-making-cross-domain-ajax-call-to-sharepoint-rest/ba-p/510001) addresses your issue.